# Expression Engine add javascript to head

Tags: expressionengine

I have been struggling with this for a while now and am stuck I am writing an extension for Expression Engine 2 (not a module) and need to add a script tag to the header of the page.

I have tried:

```
$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('added');</script>";
$this->EE->cp->add_to_head($script);
```

but im guessing this only works when its a module, i have also tried:

```
$this->EE->cp->load_package_js('file');
```

but i get the following error:

```
Call to a member function plugin() on a non-object in expressionengine/libraries/Cp.php on line 766
```

I have also tried using the hook `cp_js_end` which loads the file but its loaded after everything else thus it does not work as intended.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Note there is now a dedicated [ExpressionEngine Q&A site](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com) where you can post your question and will be more likely to receive an answer.

Comment: excellent, didnt know about that. Im pretty sure load_package_js should do it but im getting errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Low has your answer](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/cp.html#9192) .  In summary, you'll need `file` to be in a directory `javascript` in your package directory.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I'm sure that you've double-checked that you can load the .js directly in your browser in order to verify that the web server can actually get it.  Otherwise, you might want to follow @adrian-macneil's suggestion above.

Comment: yeah thanks anyway though :) will accept this answer as it works with modules.